# OpenGL: Is there a benefit to using multiple global work groups for compute shaders

Tags: opengl, synchronization, compute-shader

Is there a benefit to using multiple global work groups rather than just a single work group for compute shaders in OpenGL? I need to synchronise invocations for a large image, so global work groups won't work. I was wondering why one can't just use a single local work group to do all the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benefit of multiple work groups is bigger space.

A work group has a maximum size, and not a terribly big one either. GL 4.5 only requires that `GL_MAX_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_INVOCATIONS` will be at least 1024 invocations within a work group. A few implementations support 1536, but none higher than 1792.

The reason for the limitation is storage.

Each invocation has its own local storage. To implement a `barrier` call, the system has to be able to save this data out of the compute unit and load some new data in. If you had millions of invocations within a single work group, that would require a huge amount of data. Whereas with the current design, you only need enough storage to be able to run a few thousand invocations.

You need to design your algorithms to work within this limitation; that one thing that makes GPU compute *hard*.

Comment: I will only be writing to a couple of images, so i was wondering whether there would be a performance impact if i only used one global work group and covered the pixels with loops in that single invocation. Seeing as images are global memory that isn't an obvious problem.

Comment: Maybe i should have phrased that part of the question better.

Comment: @Jens: That's a *completely different* question. It requires no synchronization to have a invocations writing to *different pixels* of an image.